# How to enlarge ubuntu partition

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 recently by making a 5.6GB partition from the Ubiquity installer.
I  wanted to upgrade to 12.04, so I opened the Update Manager and clicked on 'Update Packages' (I was following [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-11.10-oneiric-ocelot-to-12.04-lts-precise-pangolin-desktop-and-server) guide)

After clicking, it said that there was too little space available.
So, I want to enlarge my Ubuntu partition so that there is appropriate space for upgrading.

I downloaded Gparted. I read another guide which said my computer won't boot if I resize the Ubuntu partition because '/boot will be misplaced and I will have to repair GRUB2 myself.'

So how do I do this easily?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to boot from ubuntu live cd and use gparted wich is installed by default in it.just read some tutorial before you make some changes be sure you do it correctly ps resizing process can take a long time ,watch display options under progres bar to see more detailed  info

Comment: so will ubuntu boot ?

Comment: it will if you do everything correctly.I  was able by myself to free space from another drive like /home wich is the biggest pertiton i have and then i changed-resized / partition with free mb.The only thing you should avoid do not finish until its done. it can broke partition.The process can be long depending on the size of your hard drive and amoun of files. So see advanced viewing option under the progress bar to see how many time you need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

To enlarge Ubuntu partition, what you need is LiveCD and internet connection

Use the livecd of any version of Ubuntu. Then choose `Try Ubuntu`. After that, choose Gparted Partition Editor after search in dash or use terminal then type:

```
sudo gparted
```

After that, you can resize the partition.

But if you close it without do anything after it, the grub will be broken. To make the grub effective and usable. Open terminal and type:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

The x variable depends on your harddisk. To check where is Ubuntu partition, type in terminal:

```
sudo lsusb -l
```

If there is two harddisk, the terminal will show information for /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. Check where is the Ubuntu / Linux partition. If you see the Linux partition on (example) `/dev/sda5`, the x variable is `a`. If you see the Linux partution on `/dev/sdb5`, the x variable is `b`.

Comment: i booted with live usb and opened gparted.

Comment: You can do it on livecd and liveusb. Both of them support gparted. Then do the next step (reinstall grub)

Comment: i booted with live usb and opened gparted.
there is the 33 gb drive and my ubuntu and then linux swap.
but the 33gb filesystem displays warning and does not resize-
ERROR(5) Failed to check '/dev/sda6/' mount state input/output error
Unable to read the contents of this filesystem!Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
What should i do?

Comment: I tried to resize 33gb but no avail

Comment: overcame that problem.installed ntfsprogs again with the terminal.

Comment: yeah, i want windows 7 as a option in grub too.would it detect windows7 itself?

Comment: try to execute sudo fsck wich is checking file system errors if you can summon the console while login screen or in terminal.Or go to system restore in grub and check filesystem errors.Maybe will help

Comment: @Vineet Can you copy the partition table and copy it on your posts? So I can look where is the linux, swap, and windows.
Windows 7 automatically detected by the grub reinstallation.

Comment: i have done it already.I didn't reinstall grub but it worked.